# Moving/Porting Production Android Apps from Windows 7 to Linux Based Systems Correctly

Tags: java, android, linux, windows, android-studio

Sorry in advance, there are a lot of questions in this post. I was not able to find much good information on this online so far (maybe I missed the correct search term).

The idea of this post is to migrate Android applications (that can potentially be production level on the Play Store) from Windows 7 to Linux based machines and document it correctly (like I said above I haven't found any good articles about it yet). If I find the solution myself I will post the answer.

Short background: Currently Windows 7 support ends in 2020, looking to move/port production level Android Studio applications to a Linux based system moving the following.

1. Code for each project.
2. Moving **keystores** and other important Android Studio production level files not inside of the project folder.

My main question is what is the best way to do this:

1. Copy all of the files on an external drive and move them that way?
2. Use Git to upload the app and redownload on the Linux PC?*

*I understand that Keystores and other non application settings for Android Studio will need to be moved manually with a copy to the external drive since Git generally only loads on the project level.

So far I am looking to see if anyone has experience already with this process and if they have run into any roadblocks or difficulties doing this?

Also what keystore files are necessary to copy? I understand they are in the directory below.

Is the debug.keystore the correct keystore to use for production level keystore applications?

Directory: C:\Users\username\.android

File 1: debug.keystore

File 2: default.keyset

Answer (score 0):

**No.** The `debug.keystore` and `debug.keyset` keystore files shouldn't be used in production, and *only in development*. If they are missing, they will be generated on your next build, so you won't have to worry about moving them - building the project in Android Studio on your Linux will create these for you.

To generate release keys used in production, please see [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing).